# How to exclude the same dependency, but packager to another group and module values in Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, jar, bouncycastle, gradle-dependencies

I have a dependency that bears bouncycastle:bcprov-jdl:138 to my project. It stays for bouncycastle 1.38

[image]

When I exclude it and add the 1.61 like that:

```
  implementation ('dependency:RELEASE.1.0.6')
        {
            exclude group: 'bouncycastle', module: 'bcprov-jdk14'
        }

  implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:1.61'
```

it doesn't override the excluded dependency, since it has another group. So, there are no actual substitution. Is it possible to force the 3rd aprty dependency to accept another jar packaging for the same classes, just to make it updated to a newer version?